# ¿Por qué no me deja ejecutar la app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

En la app he creado el matatopos y la función una vez le doy a un botón que lance la siguiente función, el programa se cuelga y no sé si es por un bucle infinito o por android studio en sí:

```
public void jugar(){
        while(Integer.parseInt(vidas.getText().toString()) != 0){
            numeroTopo = new ToposRandomizados(); //Creamos un objeto tipo TopoRandomizados
            numeroTopo.setIntAletorio(0); //Para depuración
            //Toast.makeText(this, "" + numeroTopo.getIntAletorio(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            switch (numeroTopo.getIntAletorio()){
                case 0:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + numeroTopo.getIntAletorio(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    contClicks = 0;
                    topo0.setOnClickListener(this);
                    topo0.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    //Tiempo: 1-2 segundos
                    miManejador.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            valorarCont();
                            topo0.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                    }, 2000);
                    break;
})))}
```

Hay 8 casos desde 0 hasta 8 inclusive, pero no voy a copiar todos ya que son casi iguales. Y al ejecutar la función en el logcat de tiempo de ejecución me dice que podría estar habiendo mucho trabajo en el hilo  principal.

Answer (score 0):

Es un loop infinito porque una vez que entra al bucle, osea que vidas != 0, las vidas no se modifican. Por lo tanto va a loopear y nunca va a cambiar el resultado de vidas!=0.

La solucion tecnica seria agregar un `vidas.text = "0"` en algun lugar dentro de los case.

Pero imagino que si esto es un juego vos lo hiciste asi para crear topos aleatoriamente durante lo que dure el juego, pero esta no es la forma de hacerlo. Solo vas a colgar el thread principal y no dejas que el usuario juegue. Te dejo un pseudocodigo de lo que deberias hacer:

```
private void jugar(){
  initGame()
  addTopos()
}
private void addTopos(){
  //Aca todo el random y el swich
  moreTopos();
}
private void moreTopos(){
  miManejador.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      addTopos();    
    }, 2000);
}
```

No estoy seguro de que se trata tu juego o que querias exactamente, pero espero que esto te sirva de guia.